# Send page within a dist folder from NodeJS Express

Tags: node.js, angular, express

We need help on an Express sendFile operation that refers to a URL within a prebuilt Angular app, packed into a dist folder. We have an Angular app being served by a NodeJS Express server. The Angular app is pre-built using

```
ng build --prod
```

resulting in a dist folder structure.

Our NodeJS Express server has a route snippet like this:

```
app.get('/', ensureAuthenticated, function (req, res) {
        logger.info('Sending file '+path.join(__dirname+'/../client/dist/client', req.originalUrl));
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname+'/../client/dist/client', req.originalUrl));
    });
```

If the URL is something like
http://localhost:4200/index.html

it works. If the app has a route like

```
http://localhost:4200/spreadsheet/uploads
```

it tries to look for __dirname/../client/dist/client/spreadsheet/uploads

which will not work. If the app was served using ng serve, the URL above is valid. But once we build it for production, the file system leaves no clue how to serve it. How should we send the Angular page back if it is something like

```
http://localhost:4200/spreadsheet/uploads
```

Comment: What is the desired path? And how is the folder structure?

Comment: I want the URL http://ocalhost:4200/spreadsheet/uploads to work. At best,I'm only able to get it to serve the main index.html. Note, this same code would work if I served it using ng serve

Comment: Sorry, I cannot help you, if you don't share desired path, where the file is stored.

Comment: I don't know how this will help you, but the file is being served on a Node server hosted on Windows 10. The path is c:\projects-new\cirrus-bluecost-rules-service\client\dist\client\index.html.  There is no specific file entries to these routes. However, if I hosted it using `ng serve`, I could pass in specific URLs and it would resolve to the specific components. When I host production generated files, I can't get it to resolve beyond the main entry point.